# Publisher sink never runs completion

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to merge two publishers but one of the completions are never run.
The following is how I create my two publishers and try to use `.sink` to observe when they complete. The `featureFlagPublisher` will finish as expected and print "featureFlagPublisher done", but the `migratePublisher` and the merged publishers will never complete.`publisher.send(completion: .finished)` is run but nothing happens.

```
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

func start() {
    let featureFlagPublisher = self.startFeatureFlagging()
    let migratePublisher = self.migrate()
    
    migratePublisher.sink { _ in
        print("migratePublisher done")
    } receiveValue: { _ in }.store(in: &cancellables)

    featureFlagPublisher.sink { _ in
        print("featureFlagPublisher done")
    } receiveValue: { _ in }.store(in: &cancellables)
    
    migratePublisher.merge(with: featureFlagPublisher)
        .sink { completion in
            print("All Done")
        } receiveValue: { _ in }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}

private func startFeatureFlagging() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    let future = Future<Bool, Never> { promise in
        FeatureFlaggingService.shared.start {
            promise(.success(true))
        }
    }
    return future.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}


private func migrate() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never>  {
    let future = Future<Bool, Never> { promise in 
        FavoriteMigrationsAPI.shared.get { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let favoriteIDs):
                    promise(.success(true))
            ...
        }
    }

    return future.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why are you using `PassthroughSubject` to convert async functions into Combine Publishers? You should use `Future` for that. Also, you shouldn't expose the fact that these functions return `PassthroughSubject`s, instead you should erase them to `AnyPublisher`.

Comment: @Dávid Pásztor Thank you for your feedback! I'm learning Combine so I'm still getting a hang of it. I'll update my example with your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was that the controller was deinitialized early and therefore the promise could not respond to the observer. So it had nothing to do with Combine or the code I posted, but with the way I initialized the controller.